# onListItemClick of Android ListView - How to activate onListItemCLick and deactivate when needed?

Tags: android, android-listview, listactivity

I have an Activity that loads all vouchers on the server to customer's phone. In that Activity, I have 2 buttons. The first button will get all vouchers that bought by the customer. The second will get the list of all available vouchers that customer can buy.

Now, the problem is, I need only `onListItemClick` for the list of available vouchers (when they click on those vouchers, they have option to buy). I use `ListView` as `ListActivity`. When I set `onListItemClick`, the event apply for bought vouchers as well.

How can I somehow deactivate `onListItemClick` event when customers view their own vouchers and activate it when customers choosing voucher to buy?

This is my code of the two buttons:

```
public void btn_Own(View v){
        if(!isConnected){
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Voucher.this, "Cannot connect to     internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            return;
            //finish();
        }


        if(email.equals("")){
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Voucher.this, "Please log in to see your voucher!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }else{
            url = "http://wswob.somee.com/wobservice.svc/checkOwnVoucher/" + email + "/";
            new checkingTask().execute();


        }
    }

public void btn_Shop(View v){
        if(!isConnected){
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Voucher.this, "Cannot connect to internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            return;
            //finish();
        }

        url = "http://wswob.somee.com/wobservice.svc/showVoucher";
        new MyTask().execute();
    }
```

I'm new to Android, so I just came to know that I have to use custom adapter to do so (as far as I know). But I wonder how can I do that while I'm using asynctask and pass different parameters when I need that do execute different tasks from web service.

This is how I get the list after calling web service:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);


        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                Voucher.this, voucherList,
                R.layout.voucher_list, new String[]{"detail","price"},
                new int[]{R.id.detail, R.id.price});

        setListAdapter(null);

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Comment: refer to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7779199/2145360

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use setEnabled to true or false to control when the user can actually click the link or button.

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot, that's the easiest way without using custom adapter. `ListView.setEnabled(false)`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the button click events of activity,you have two button,onclick of frist but just make the listview Itemclicklistener disable after loading all vocher from server and on click of second button which  loads available vochers only make your listviewItem clickable.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so but the information I found was all about custom adapter. If I use customer adapter, I don't really sure how to implement async as the same time. Now, I put async in the same class and pass different links whenever I click different buttons to do different jobs.